# Calling the Right Fragment from my Parent Activity class when Share from Device Image Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, intentfilter

I have a  Main activity which is the base activity for my other fragments that implement this basic structure.

In one of my fragments I have a pick from Gallery. However, I also want the onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) method inside my Fragment Java class to be trigger after a user selects which photo to be shared from the Gallery.

Any ideas how I might achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

override the onActivityResult method in your fragment file.
And, use the startActivityForResult method when you are launching the gallery app.

For those methods, googling!